# Jquery Syntax error, unrecognized expression on attribute selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have html div with one attribute.

```html
div exp_attribute="{"prop_val_name":1}">mydiv</div>
```

I tried to trigger click on it via jQuery like

```js
$('div[exp_attribute={"prop_val_name":1}]').click();   // not working
$('div[exp_attribute=\\{"prop_val_name":1\\}]').click();   // not working with escaping special chars
$('div[exp_attribute=\\{\\"prop_val_name\\":1\\}]').click();   // not working with escaping more special chars
```

but keep getting error

```js
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: div[exp_attribute=\{\"prop_val_name\":1\}]
```

so any idea how to handle the issue?

Comment: Escape the colon too, and don't escape the double quotes.

Comment: `<div data-name="1">mydiv</div>` seems a cleaner solution - unless there's a very specific reason you need code like this.

Comment: @Andy ya you right but this attribute is coming from somewhere else not in my control.

Comment: @Teemu ya it worked however have to escape double quotes too and colon

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought @user889030. I'm annoyed on your behalf.

Comment: Ah, the double quotes are a part of the attribute value, then yes, you need to escape those too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to escape everything

```js
$('div[exp_attribute=\\{\\"prop_val_name\\"\\:1\\}]').click();
```